# How do I connect to TTY/COM (/dev/ttyUSB0)?

Tags: command-line, tty

I am running Ubuntu for the first time by booting from a USB drive. Now I have plugged in a USB-to-serial converter which has been recognized and automatically added as `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

How do I access `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22545/9454

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use one of screen's lesser known features:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: if you need to specify the baud rate, add it after the serial device. eg, for 57600 baud: `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 57600`

Comment: Note that if you want to detach from the terminal and CTRL-D isn't cutting it, use CTRL-A then k to kill screen. I had to use this with the TTY at ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty provided by Docker for Mac. CTRL-A then d will work too, but will leave your screen session running, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Most people using this will also want to specify -ixon: `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200,-ixon`. If this isn't specified and the remote device ever sends a 0x13 (^S), screen will start buffering everything you type and it won't send it until the remote device sends a 0x11 (^Q). See `info screen 'Window Types'` for more on this.

Answer (score 13):

```
busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241

Answer (score 13):

You could use tio - a simple tty terminal I/O application:

```
tio /dev/ttyUSB0
```

See http://tio.github.io

Comment: Available on MinGW! Great!

Comment: This is an incredible piece of software. Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 7):

You can use picocom, it is a minimal dumb-terminal emulation program. Basic usage is something like this (change 11520 to the desired baud rate):

```
$ picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

You have all the options you may want from a dumb-terminal program, like stop bits, parity, local echo, carriage return / line feed / backspace / delete / tab translation, X/Y/Z-modem and ASCII transfer integration, etc.

See `man picocom` and  `picocom --help` for further information.

Answer (score 6):

you can use ckermit also. It should be in the repository. After installing it create a file in your home directory called `.mykermrc` then add the 5 following lines:

```
set line /dev/ttyUSB0   
set flow-control none  
set carrier-watch off  
set speed 115200  
connect
```

parameters can be adjusted as necessary.
save the file.
to start it

```
sudo kermit
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use putty. Its an ssh/serial/telnet client for Windows and Linux. You can download it from http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Networking/PuTTY-347.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If you need to configure it first, then

```
minicom -s
```

If you're wondering where's the meta key in MacOS, you will need to plan an escape. For other options, -h for help.

Answer (score 2):

I was using puTTY to connect to the serial ports. But don't forget to add your user to dialout: `sudo adduser <username> dialout` then reboot the system.

After that, you can use puTTY for serial connections such as `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: it is actually enough to simply log out and back in again.

Answer (score 2):

Needed Mint 17.1 to talk to my Arduino, after a little chasing around, it turns out that your user must be part of the `dialout` group to use the tty. This should apply to Ubuntu as well. You can do so either by running the command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout username
```

Or graphically, by using:

Administration → Users & Groups → Manage Groups

In which case you would go to the line for `dialout`, check the properties to ensure that *`username`* is ticked, if not *`username`* must be added.

This worked for me and by the look of lots of posts others have had the same problem.

Comment: -1 for `sudo gedit /etc/group`. Don't. Just don't. Learn how to add a user to a group using `usermod` or `adduser` for example. And your post is more of a comment rather than an answer to the question, because you don't actually show how to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Tio without GUI or CuteCom with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lucid and a Dynamode USB to RS232 cable:

```
Plugged it in
ran kermit
set line /dev/ttyUSB0    <<-- mind the capitals/lowecase
connect
set speed 9600
...
```

and successfully connected to an RS232 port on an OpenVMS server.