# Is there a command that can be sent into a usb port to request the system's time?

Tags: tty, time, serial-port, embedded-system

I'd like to add a functionality to a project I'm working on, in which as soon as an external controller device powers on, it sends a time-request/command to a ttyusb port of an Ubuntu PC, and the Ubuntu PC sends back the system's time and date. Does such a command exists in Ubuntu?

for example something like:

```
'timeReq' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

In which "time" is the command that would echo back the system's time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to TTY/COM (/dev/ttyUSB0)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40959/how-do-i-connect-to-tty-com-dev-ttyusb0)

Comment: @K7AAY Not really, I'm specifically asking about a special command that would echo back the time and date on my Ubuntu system. The answer you have provided is just to interact with the ttyUSBxx port. But thank you

Comment: You probably think that you can redirect only `echo` output. That is wrong.

Comment: Does the edit to the question explain better what you're looking for?

Comment: Seems like you need a service running the Ubuntu PC and *listening* on the USB port. It listens for input from your device, and responds. Random input from the USB port will be ignored, and random *commands* certainly will be ignored.

Comment: @user535733 That is correct. I was just wondering if Ubuntu has any feature that allows for such functionality

Comment: No: Allowing random external devices without login to issue shell commands would be a tremendous security hole. Imagine all the damage a nefarious USB device could cause!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that outputs system time is `date`.

You can use format parameters to output only the time.

Also you can send its output to USB using `>` redirection.

Example

```
date +%R > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The user needs to be a mamber of `dialout` group or have some other permissions to be able to write there.

You can use `man date` to see for other formatting options.

Comment: Just to clarify, If I send "date +%R > /dev/ttyUSB0" as a string from my embedded device to the ttyUSB0 port, will Ubuntu recognize that as a shell command and then send the result back to the USB0 port?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sending back to USB port". This command in Ubuntu will send time to USB port. Everything else about some embedded device is uclear.

Comment: What I mean is, if you write that command (date +%R > /dev/ttyUSB0) in your terminal, it will send the time to the USB port correct? but what I intend is to ask for the time from the embedded device. "a time request" to put it on other words

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You can try yourself and see what this command deoes without redirection.