# when i try to uplaod to dev/ttyUSB0 it doesn't work

Tags: usb, serial-port

it gives me this error

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied
```

PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Pls add the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` to your question. You should be in the same group as the device.

Comment: you can not simply 'upload' to a USB serial device, which I assume you are trying. This will probably give you an idea: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40959/how-do-i-connect-to-tty-com-dev-ttyusb0

Comment: @VincentGerris he's using avrdude, "utility to download/upload/manipulate the ROM and EEPROM contents of AVR microcontrollers" https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do not have permission, as the error message says; for some operations `avrdude` needs root privileges.

To solve: add `sudo` in front of the command you used.

Comment: Normally the right solution will be to add the user to the same group as the device. Running commands with sudo / elevateted rights should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself to the serial port user group:

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourusername`

and then reboot.

Depending on your distro, the name of the group might change to `uucp` or something else.